# Add styling to format.html outputted from Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

reports.rb

```
def method
  if self.name == "Maintenance History"
    'maintenance_history'
  elsif self.name == "Outstanding Maintenance"
    'outstanding_maintenance'
  elsif self.name == "Idle Time Report"
   'idle_time_report'
  end
end

def maintenance_history
  maintenance_history.where(....)
end

def outstanding_maintenance
  outstanding_maintenance.where(....)
end

def idle_time_report
  idle_time_report.where(....)
end
```

reports_controller

```
  def show
    @report = Report.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
```

show.html.haml

```
= render @report.method, :report => @report
```

I would like to format the html table in my view with the following tag `%table.table.datatable#datatable`

This:

```
%table.table.datatable#datatable
  = render @report.method, :report => @report
```

does not work...

Comment: Add a ruleset to your stylesheet targeting `#datatable`?

Comment: See how I display my report in my view. I simply call the controller show. Because there are multiple reports, they should be created on the fly, but I need to add the datatable css tag to the table so I can enable sorting..

Comment: `format.html` without any arguments just call `render "show"`. Add styles as you would normally.

Comment: I need to pass in which report I want to show. Then how would I add the CSS based on my code above? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly, it's that the different tables require different styles depending on the report.  Just as you're using the name of the report in the controller to determine the scope, you could use some attribute of the report in the view to add a class or other identifying attribute to the HTML.

As a simple example, you could create a helper for your view *exactly* like your `method` controller method, like:

```
# some helper for the reports
module ReportsHelper

  # the `method` method from your controller, migrated to a helper
  def report_table_class(report)
    if report.name == "Maintenance History"
      'maintenance_history'
    elsif report.name == "Outstanding Maintenance"
      'outstanding_maintenance'
    elsif report.name == "Idle Time Report"
      'idle_time_report'
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your view, you could use that to demarcate the table or a parent element, which you could use as a target for your style selector:

```
%table#datatable{:class => ['table', 'datatable', report_table_class(@report)]}
```

And finally in your CSS:

```
table.maintenance_history {
  // style accordingly
}

table.idle_time_report {
  // style accordingly
}
```